# Available Azure service connections in Azure Pipelines is empty, even when I already have valid service connections?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to configure a task in Azure Pipelines. Under the section for "Azure subscription", the dropdown list of Available Azure service connections is empty. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHSGQ.png).

However, if i click on "Manage", I can clearly see that the service connection already exists. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCuK8.png).

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you authorized to use that service connection? Are all pipelines? Look at the service connection security.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found to this problem seems to indicate that this is a bug.

If I go to the service connection and verify the connection again ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLvDG.png)), that seems to "refresh" the dropdown list of available service connections elsewhere in Azure Pipelines.